# A spinning electron is not a current-carrying loop

Tags: electromagnetism, dipole

The statement in the title of this question looks trivial, but it took me some days to wrap my head around. There is at least one decisive distinction between an electron (with its spin) and a current-carrying wire loop: A time-dependent external magnetic field can induce an emf in the wire, but it cannot do so with the electron, as there is (surprise!) no wire. At least in this respect, the Ampère model of a dipole (current going round in a tiny circle) seems to be a much poorer choice than the Gilbert model of a dipole (two magnetic monopoles).

This has dramatic consequences, for instance, on how to compute the total energy for collections of electromagnets as opposed to collections of permanent magnets. Jackson et al.'s Classical Electrodynamics hints at this (at least I believe so) around and after Eq. (5.151) on p. 250 in the 2006 German edition.

And now for the questions: Am I right? And is there any textbook or paper that devotes a more in-depth discussion to this topic? I found none so far.

Comment: As [How does a spinning electron produce a magnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/111538/37364) shows, there are problems with the idea that an electron is a point charge traveling in a circle.

Comment: Please keep in mind that spin had to be **assigned** to elementary particles , as the electron, so that conservation of angular momentum would hold at the quantum mechanical particle level interactions.  It is an experimental fact that electrons are points and do have a spin .

Comment: [The electron is not only a charge but also an intrinsic magnetic dipole. The electrons magnetic moment is well measured and has a constant value. With more emphasis of that fact, the need in any motion around the nucleus as the source of the magnetic field of the electron is obsolet.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646363/is-there-a-classical-explanation-of-why-the-electron-in-the-ground-state-of-a-hy)

Comment: I know that Zangwill's *Modern Electrodynamics* is careful to draw the distinction between magnetization due to "bound currents" vs. due to "inherent dipoles", but I can't remember whether it discusses energy in this regard.  He does include a long list of references in all his chapters, though, so it might be worth a look.  If this question is still open when I have a chance to look at my copy, I'll post an update.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes, Zangwill's book is indeed quite helpful. Thanks for pointing it out!